# perforce: how to find the changelist which deletes a line for a file?

Tags: perforce

So I just found that someone removed a line from a "global" file and the removal is very likely wrong. I need to trace which changelist did the removal, but it is a global file, everyone edits it from many branches. I randomly picked a couple, they both have that line. Any suggestion to do this more systematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest collecting all change# of the file, then using binary search, grabbing each of the change, and grepping for specific line you are looking for, and the character '-' or '<' (depends on your du setting) in the first line.

The line below will give you all the changes:

```
p4 filelog yourfile.cpp | egrep "^... \#[0-9]+ change" | cut '-d ' -f 4
```

If you do not want to do binary search manually or write a code to do that in shell or anything else, then I would suggest a brute force, and scan all changes in search for that line.
For example:

```
p4 filelog yourfile.cpp | egrep "^... \#[0-9]+ change" | cut '-d ' -f 4 | while read change ; do
    p4 describe $change | egrep "^<.*your line that was deleted"
    [ $? = 0 ] && echo $change
done
```

Output in my example:
<    /* remove the confirmation record for the outstanding write if found */
234039

Where 234039 is the change number that contains your deletion.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

[Time-lapse view](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/time_lapse.html) is a really good tool for this. You can check out [this video](http://ftp.perforce.com/media/tlv/tlv.html) for a better idea of how it works.

Comment: Time-lapse view is indeed the easiest way to answer this question. I do this all the time, and Time-lapse view makes it very easy to do.

Comment: +1 I like what I see in that video. I am not using GUI but I see great value of this feature when one uses. I would say it is definitively the best answer if someone uses P4V.